# Show that any set in a metric space can be written as the intersection of open sets

Tags: metric-spaces

> Show that any set contained in the metric space $(X, d)$ can be
>   written as the intersection of open sets.

Definitions: A set $A \subseteq X$ is open if $\forall x \in A$, $\exists \varepsilon>0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \subseteq A$. A set $C \subseteq X$ is closed if and only if $X \setminus C$ is open.

I also know that the intersection of a finite collection of open sets is open and that any open ball contained in $X$ is open. How can I prove this question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Singletons $\{a\}$ are closed sets, so their complements are open. For any set $A \subseteq X$ consider the following:
$$A=\bigcap_{a \in A^{c}}\{a\}^c.$$
Observe that each $\{a\}^c$ is open and once you verify the set equality (which is not that difficult) you have $A$ as the intersection of open sets.

Comment: Therefore the property relies not on $X$ being a metric space, but on it being a $T_1$ topological space

Comment: Thought: Would it work to say
$$A = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ x\in X \mid \mathrm{dist} (A, x) < \frac{1}{n} \right\}$$
for an arbitrary $A\subseteq X$? If this set equality holds and the sets we intersect are really open, then we manage to solve this with a _countable_ intersection.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen $X=\Bbb R$ and $A=X-\{0\}$ does not work with that trick (though it is even open by itself)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You are right, thank you for that easy counterexample. (_Addition:_ My method even fails for an open bounded interval inside $X=\mathbb{R}$.) I really felt like using the distance there. Is it true that any subset of a metric space is a _countable_ intersection of open sets?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I considered this worth a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370097/when-are-all-subsets-intersections-of-countably-many-open-sets)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen In a uniform space, the intersection of all uniform neighbourhoods of a set is the closure of the set. For metric spaces, we can do with a countable intersection and have $$\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \biggl\{ x \in X : \operatorname{dist}(A,x) < \frac{1}{n}\biggr\} = \overline{A}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, I was starting to realize something like that. I found a question with the problem to prove that every _closed_ subset of a metric space was a countable intersection of open sets, and its answers used my $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ x\in X \mid \mathrm{dist} (A, x) < \frac{1}{n} \right\}$ approach. So since that is the thing that works in metric spaces, we could also ask about a "classification" of _topological_ spaces with the property that every _closed_ subset is the countable intersection of open subsets.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gδ_space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_space)

Comment: I am not clear why the expression $A=\bigcap_{a \in A^{c}}\{a\}^c$ with respect to metric space X is valid for infinite intersection of open sets.